# p-values of the coefficients or AIC for model selection in multiple regression

Tags: multiple-regression, p-value, model-selection, regression-coefficients, aic

I´ve got two models from a multiple linear regression (A and B, see below) and don´t know which to select. I want to predict a value called AW as good as possible, so I´d like to have the highest r². 
My tolerance for significance is p < 0,05 (It´s agricultural topic).

On the side of the smallest AIC it should be model A. 
On the side of the highest r² with p-value lower than 0.05 it should be model B. 
Can I choose model B and ignore the non-signifcant p-values of the three variables?
Or is it adding more risk to the prediction, although a higher r²? 
Isn´t the risk showing up in the total p-value of the regression? 
And because of my chosen p < 0.05 am I still ok?

## Model A

```
AIC= 164.9312
Call:
lm(formula = AW ~ VO, data = Rheo_four_90)

Residuals:
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-11.7638  -7.6916  -0.9902   5.6229  24.9090 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -261.91960   54.02660  -4.848 9.76e-05 ***
VO             0.40251    0.08237   4.887 8.92e-05 ***

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 9.401 on 20 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5442,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.5214 
F-statistic: 23.88 on 1 and 20 DF,  p-value: 8.923e-05
```

## Model B

```
AIC= 167.3584
Call:
lm(formula = AW ~ GF + VZ_DL + PR + VO, data = Rheo_four_90)

Residuals:
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-15.532  -4.662  -1.358   3.134  19.557 

Coefficients:
         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept) -193.5623    72.1190  -2.684   0.0157 * 
GF             0.5868     0.5242   1.119   0.2785   
VZ_DL         -9.1682     6.4576  -1.420   0.1738   
PR           -10.4747     6.5034  -1.611   0.1257   
VO             0.4780     0.1610   2.969   0.0086 **

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 9.401 on 17 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6125,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.5214 
F-statistic: 6.719 on 4 and 17 DF,  p-value: 0.001963
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the Adjusted R-squared happens to be identical in both models. The fact that the un-adjusted $R^2$ is higher in Model B is just a result of fitting more variables in the second model. Every time you add explanatory variables the $R^2$ increases, although the [increase may just be due to noise](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/multiple-regession-analysis-use-adjusted-r-squared-and-predicted-r-squared-to-include-the-correct-number-of-variables) - this is the reason behind the use of the adjusted $R^2$.

Likewise, the [AIC value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) for Model A is lower, also penalizing the unnecessary complexity of Model B.

Comment: Thank you. The adjusted R² is something I didn´t looked at. In adding more variables its increase the risk of being wrong? But if I accept alpha with 0.05 and there are no more costs in validating the variables, why not choose the more complex model B? Because the p-values of the variables are higher?

Comment: Sorry that I pressed to early enter.